# Bar diagram with error bars in Scilab

Tags: plot, statistics, scilab

I am trying to find a way to include error bars on a bar diagram. Sadly, I could only find error bars for normal 2d plots. A really sloppy way I tried to fix it with:

```
close();

x=[2, 4, 8];
y=[0.2 0.12 0.06; 0.17 0.22 0.05; 0.19 0.20 0.07];
dev=[0.08 0.08 0.03; 0.03 0.05 0.02; 0.04 0.06 0.02];

bar(x, (y+dev), 'w--')
bar(x, y)
```

But that doesn’t show me the lower boundary (And it doesn’t look good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `errbar()` over your bar diagram. If you look at how `bar()` works, it plots every column of `y` separately and then shifts them to the right or to the left in the horizontal axis.

For this to work, you need to retrieve how much each set was shifted and add that value to the `x` input of `errbar()`. To get a [result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvN5F.png), you can use the following code (updated after asker's note):

```
x=[2, 4, 8];
y=[0.2 0.12 0.06; 0.17 0.22 0.05; 0.19 0.20 0.07];
dev=[0.08 0.08 0.03; 0.03 0.05 0.02; 0.04 0.06 0.02];
bar(x,y)

//get the entity handler
e=gce();

//loop over the entity to retrive x_shift values
for i = 1:length(y,'c')
    x_shift(i,:) = e.children(i).x_shift;
end

//flip x_shift vertically
x_shift = x_shift($:-1:1,:);

//plot the error bars
for i = 1:length(y,'c')
    errbar(x + x_shift(i), y(:,i)', dev(:,i)', dev(:,i)');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@luispauloml
Thanks for your answer. While implementing it I found a small error. In the for-loops you have to use the size of y and not x. It just worked because y happened to be a square matrix. I made y one row bigger and changed the deviation to the same values of y to see if the matrizes are defined the right way and I don't mix up the values.

```
x=[2; 4; 8];
y=[0.2 0.12 0.06 0.1; 0.17 0.22 0.05  0.1; 0.19 0.20 0.07  0.1];
dev=[0.2 0.12 0.06 0.1; 0.17 0.22 0.05  0.1; 0.19 0.20 0.07  0.1];

bar(x,y)

//get the entity handler
e=gce();

//loop over the entity to retrive x_shift values
for i = 1:size(y,'c')
    x_shift(i,:) = e.children(i).x_shift;
end

//flip x_shift vertically
x_shift = x_shift($:-1:1,:);

//plot the error bars
for i = 1:size(y,'c')
    errbar(x + x_shift(i), y(:,i)', dev(:,i)', dev(:,i)');
end
```